# "Nintex" tag? Really?

Tags: discussion, tagging

[This tag](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintex) just popped in [during a review on the main site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/58340).

Should it even exist in the first place?? Nintex Workflow related questions are off topic as are all question about third parties product, so I wonder - is there any use or benefit we could get from having this tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is off topic, It seeming always pops back up because people keep asking questions. We close them off topic, they eventually expire and the tag goes away, only to pop back up again because someone asks a question and tags it as such.

Comment: yep, my worries were mostly caused from the actual proposal of creating a tag wiki for it.

Comment: My bad... I was looking for tags I could help update and I saw that one. I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: No worries James

Comment: So, it IS useful to find off topic questions

Comment: @Jammin4CO, not really. The off-topic questions tend to be spotted and flagged rapidly anyway :)